# Targeting select devices and the device.model string

Tags: cordova

I'm looking at running specific code targeting iPhone 3GS, 4 and 4S. Is the best way to detect for these specific devices through *device.model* using the Device Phonegap Plugin? ... and if so, is there any list out there that says what each device gives out for the device.model?

For example:

- iPhone 5 device.model = iPhone5,1
- iPhone 4S device.model = ?
- iPhone 4 device.model = iPhone3,1
- iPhone 3GS device.model = ?

I want to be sure I am targeting the right devices

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question and found a page listing all the identifiers for Apple devices (what device.model gives you)

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models under the *Identifiers* column.